# Solving an equation for k_t in a modified Solow model

Tags: macroeconomics, solow

I want to solve my modified solow equation for k_t to get the steady state. But since I also inclueded the marginal product for the price of Energy its pretty difficult for me to find a solution.

here is the equation

$$
\frac{\delta \cdot k_t}{s \cdot A \cdot k_t^\alpha} =  \left(\frac{P_e}{\gamma \cdot A \cdot k_t^\alpha}\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}
$$

I want to solve for $k_t$

Here is the initial equation.

$$
0 = s \cdot A \cdot k_t^\alpha \cdot \left(\frac{P_e}{\gamma \cdot A \cdot k_t^\alpha}\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}} - \delta \cdot k_t
$$

I would be really thankful if someone could help me or give me a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\delta \cdot k_t}{s \cdot A \cdot k_t^\alpha} & = &  \left(\frac{P_e}{\gamma \cdot A \cdot k_t^\alpha}\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}
\\
\frac{\delta}{s \cdot A}  \cdot k_t^{1-\alpha} & = & \left(\frac{P_e}{\gamma \cdot A}\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}} \cdot k_t^{-\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\alpha}
\\
k_t^{1-\alpha} \cdot k_t^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\alpha} & = & \frac{s \cdot A}{\delta} \cdot \left(\frac{P_e}{\gamma \cdot A}\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}
\\
k_t^{1-\frac{\alpha}{\gamma-1}} & = & \frac{s \cdot A}{\delta} \cdot \left(\frac{P_e}{\gamma \cdot A}\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
And then you just substitute the parameters and take the right hand side to the proper power.